# What is a staggered intercalation compound？

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, superconductivity

As what the title say. what is the basic concept of that?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it would be more appropriate for chemistry SE

Comment: The community here is very light on solid state physics folk, leading to comments such as the above. Even 40 years ago intercalated materials and their physics were present at American Physical Society meetings. Yes, this is physics not chemistry. See, for example, https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.91.081111 - note it is in Phys Rev. It also answers the question in the abstract, so feel free to close as Googleable...

Comment: @JonCuster My problem with this question is rather that the OP could have given a *little* more detail.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch - fair enough, but that is highly field and breadth dependent. I’ve never done intercalated materials but can still recall a long discussion at a poster at an APS meeting in 1984...

Answer (score 1):

An intercalated material is one that has something else stuffed between layers of a crystal. Physics investigations of these materials have a long history going back to impurities in bulk graphite or other hcp-type crystals.

As interesting effects in 2D materials have come to the fore in the last decade or so, intercalation has proved quite useful, where you slide one layer of a given 2D material inbetween layers of other 2D materials, ranging from one layer in a stack, to one layer of material A for every $n$ layers of material B, down to alternating 2D layers. This allows mixing and matching of electrical properties, with overall properties depending on various couplings (A-A, A-B, B-B in varying proportions).

As one example, the first journal article pulled up by Google, look at [a Phys. Rev. B article](https://journals.aps.org/prb/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevB.91.081111) on the properties of layered CaAs FeAs layers. To quote the abstract:

> We predict that CaFeAs$_{2}$, a newly discovered iron-based high-temperature (T$_{c}$) superconductor, is a staggered intercalation  compound  that  integrates  topological  quantum  spin  Hall  (QSH)  and  superconductivity  (SC). CaFeAs$_{2}$ has a structure with staggered CaAs and FeAs layers. While the FeAs layers are known to be responsible for high T$_{c}$ superconductivity, we show that with spin orbital coupling each CaAs layer is a Z$_{2}$ topologically nontrivial two-dimensional QSH insulator and the bulk is a three-dimensional weak topological insulator. In the superconducting state, the edge states in the CaAs layer are natural one-dimensional topological superconductors.The staggered intercalation of QSH and SC provides us a unique opportunity to realize and explore physics, such as Majorana modes and Majorana fermion chains.

So, intercalation materials, and particularly here staggered intercalation materials, allow one to explore some very interesting physics.